# List all files from outside Windows 7 VM

Tags: python, windows, virtualbox, samba

I am running Win7 in VirtualBox VM and my goal is listing the list of files that are inside the Win7 VM from outside the VM, for example, I want to use python client. I have network access to the VM, is the best practice is sharing all the files and folders using Samba and accessing through the network with python client? Any more suggestions? I want also to be able to download the files. (The client will run on OSX/Linux)

Answer (score 2):

You can use WinSCP - https://winscp.net/eng/download.php

This will help you to access the files with a nice GUI. Make sure you select the commander option while installing WinSCP. This will allow you to have two pane - one for your host and one for your VM.

If you are planning to make the files downloadable for a private network users, then you can install Xampp server inside your VM and place the files to be downloaded inside "C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\" and share the URL (e.g. 192.168.10.2:5000\dashboard" with the users inside same network. So that they can download the required files.

Comment: I am planning to use it programmatically, is the winscp is the protocol?

Comment: Winscp is a desktop app that uses ssh to connect to your remote machine. It is not a command line tool. Also, make sure you enable ssh in your remote machine before trying to connect using winscp.